# javascript - calculate success rate for every 10 objects in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, rate

i have the following array which can contain up to 30 objects its dynamic for each user.

```
const array = [
{name: x, succeeded: true},
{name: y, succeeded: false},
{name: z, succeeded: true},
]
```

what i need to do is make a function which will check the success rate for every 10 objects and add a key called "successRate" with the success rate of the last 10 objects depending on the times succeeded was true. if there are less than 10 objects left it will calculate the success rate on the amount of objects left (for example if there are 27 objects in the array it will check the success rate for the first 10 then the other 10 then for 7).

the output for the example array should be:

```
const array = [
{name: x, succeeded: true, successRate: 66.66%},
{name: y, succeeded: false, successRate: 66.66%},
{name: z, succeeded: true, successRate: 66.66%},
]
```

however if the array's length is for example 13, it will first check the first 10 objects and give them all the same successrate, then check the other 3 and give them all the same success rate.
for example:

```
const array = [
{name: 1, succeeded: true, successRate: 80%},
{name: 2, succeeded: true, successRate: 80%},
{name: 3, succeeded: true, successRate: 80%},
{name: 4, succeeded: true, successRate: 80%},
{name: 5, succeeded: false, successRate: 80%},
{name: 6, succeeded: true, successRate: 80%},
{name: 7, succeeded: true, successRate: 80%},
{name: 8, succeeded: false, successRate: 80%},
{name: 9, succeeded: true, successRate: 80%},
{name: 10, succeeded: true, successRate: 80%},
{name: 11, succeeded: false, successRate: 66.66%},
{name: 12, succeeded: true, successRate: 66.66%},
{name: 13, succeeded: true, successRate: 66.66%},
]
```

Comment: Any first 10 objects? First 10 object of same name? Your question is unclear. Also please share your attempt so far.

Comment: can you cehck out the other example i added? basically i need the success rate of every 10 objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution using recursion to chunk the array...

```js
const
  array = [{ name: 1 }, { name: 2, succeeded: true }, { name: 3, succeeded: true }, { name: 4, succeeded: true }, { name: 5, succeeded: false }, { name: 6, succeeded: true }, { name: 7, succeeded: true }, { name: 8, succeeded: false }, { name: 9, succeeded: true }, { name: 10, succeeded: true }, { name: 11, succeeded: false }, { name: 12, succeeded: true }, { name: 13, succeeded: true },],

  calculateSucessRate = (arr) => {
    const { sum, length } = arr.reduce((a, { succeeded }) => {
      if (succeeded !== undefined) {
        a.length += 1;
        a.sum += succeeded;
      }
      return a;
    }, { sum: 0, length: 0 });

    return sum / length;
  },

  successRateByChunk = (arr, chunkSize) => {
    if (!arr.length) { return []; }

    const chunk = arr.slice(0, chunkSize);
    const successRate = `${calculateSucessRate(chunk) * 100}%`;

    return [
      ...chunk.map(o => ({ ...o, successRate })),
      ...successRateByChunk(arr.slice(chunkSize), chunkSize)
    ];
  };

console.log(successRateByChunk(array, 10));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: epic function man im going to use this as this is a function which gives the final result and works very nice. thank you

Comment: and what makes this function more epic is that i can use my pagination variable as the second arrgument this way i always keep the calculation work with the current page :) amazing code

Comment: I have another small problem which i'm sure you can fix in the function to make it work the best! 
inside the array i also have some object which does not include the key "succeded" (they are not yet true or false). these objects make everything show NaN :( could you please fix the function to make it ignore those object? (for example if a chunk of 10 had 3 objects without succeeded key the calculation will be divide by 7 and not by 10). thank you very much

Comment: edited to accommodate your comment by adding a check in the reduce and summing the length as well as sum of true values.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```js
const array = [
  {name: 1, succeeded: true,},
  {name: 2, succeeded: true},
  {name: 3, succeeded: true},
  {name: 4, succeeded: true},
  {name: 5, succeeded: false},
  {name: 6, succeeded: true},
  {name: 7, succeeded: true},
  {name: 8, succeeded: false},
  {name: 9, succeeded: true,},
  {name: 10, succeeded: true},
  {name: 11, succeeded: false},
  {name: 12, succeeded: true},
  {name: 13, succeeded: true},
]

const arrays = [];
const size = 10;
// first split input into chunks of 10 or less
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i += size) {
   arrays.push(array.slice(i, i + size));
}

const result = arrays.forEach(chunk => { // do following for each chunk

   //find number of succeeded items
   let succeeded = chunk.filter(item => item.succeeded).length;

   // find success rate based on number of items in chunk
   let rate = `${(succeeded/chunk.length) * 100}%`;

   // add current success rate to every item in chunk
   chunk.forEach(item => item.successRate = rate);
});

console.log(arrays.flat());
```

Comment: legendary bro thank you very much this is exactly what i was looking for

Comment: by the way what would be the best way to spread all these arrays into 1 new array and keep the order exactly as it was (asuming i dont know its size)?

Comment: use a `.flatMap()` instead of `.forEach()`

Comment: @pilchard i get the same result what is the difference?

Comment: you need to assign the result of the `flatMap` to a new variable.

Comment: Just updated the answer with a `flat()` ^